# Is there an operator have for the essential spectrum the unit disk?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Is there a bounded linear operator  $T \in l^2(\mathbb{N})$ have for the essential spectrum the unit disk of $\mathbb{C}$; i.e, such that $\sigma_{e}(T)=\textbf{D}(0, 1)$; where $\textbf{D}(0, 1):=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : |\lambda|\leq 1\}.$

Comment: I remember that this is either the left shift or the right shift operator.  Try them out - one of them will probably work.

Comment: Hello stephan. It's well known that  the left shift $L$ and the right shift  $R$  operator had   $\sigma_{e}(L)=\sigma_{e}(R)=\textbf{C}(0, 1);$ where $\textbf{C}(0, 1)$ is the unit circl.

Comment: How about this?  $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ is isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb N \times \mathbb N)$.  Let $T$ be the map $T(a)_{m,n} = a_{m,n+1}$.  (I'm just throwing out ideas here, so that's why these aren't answers.)

Comment: I think you did not understand what I mean. I  looking  for the essential spectrum $\sigma_{e}(T),$ not for the spectrum $\sigma(T)$;  the essential spectrum is defined by $\sigma_{e}(T):=\{\lambda \in \mathbb{C} : (\lambda I - T) \text{ is not a Fredholm operator}\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any compact $K\subset \mathbb C$, there exists $T\in B(\ell^2(\mathbb N))$ with $\sigma_e(T)=K$.

Let $\{P_n\}$ be a pairwise orthogonal sequence of infinite projections that add to $I$ (construction at the end). Take $\{q_n\}\subset K$ to be a countable dense set. Now define $T$ such that
$$
TP_n=q_nP_N.
$$
That is, $T$ is $q_nI$ on each subspace $P_n\ell^2(\mathbb N)$. First, note that $\sigma(T)=K$. Indeed, each $q_n$ is an eigenvalue. If $r\in\mathbb C\setminus K$, let $d=\operatorname{dist}(r,K)$. Define $S$ to be given by
$$
SP_n=\frac1{q_n-r}\,P_n.
$$
Then $S$ is bounded (because $|q_n-r|\geq d$ for all $n$) and $S(T-r I)=I$; this shows that $\sigma(T)\subset\overline{\{q_n\}}=K$.  As the multiplicity of each $q_n$ is infinite, $\{q_n\}\subset \sigma_e(T)$. As the essential spectrum is closed and contained in $\sigma(T)$, we get that $\sigma_e(T)=K$.

---

**Construction of the projections.** Let $\{e_k\}\subset\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ be an orthonormal basis. Let $\{G_n\}\subset \mathbb N$ be a partition of $\mathbb N$ into infinite sets. Now let $P_n$ be the projection onto the span of $\{e_k:\ k\in G_n\}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you have a reference (book or article) on this topic, please advise me.

Comment: Not really. Diagonal/multiplication operators are considered pretty much in every textbook, but usually in the exercise sections as it is fairly straightforward to deal with them.

Comment: Anyway, the key point here is for you to be able to show that if $\{e_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis and $T$ is defined by $Te_k=\alpha_ke_k$ and extended by linearity, then $\|T\|=\sup\{|\alpha_k|:\ k\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $T$ on $\ell^2(\mathbb N \times \mathbb N)$, with $T(a)_{m,n} = a_{m,n+1}$.  Then for $|\lambda| < 1$, elements of the form $(b_m \lambda ^n)_{m,n}$ are in the kernel of $T - \lambda I$.  So the kernel has infinite dimension.

Also $T$ on $L^2(D(0,1))$ (which is isomorphic to $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$) given by $Tf(z) = z f(z)$.  Then the cokernel of $T - \lambda I$ is infinite dimensional for all $\lambda \in D(0,1)$.